# Writing a database migration that turns datetime null:false to true

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm trying to write a database migration that changes the datetime fields in my join table from null to true but something isn't working correctly. Here's my code:

```
class ChangeDateColumnsInCirclesUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_column :circles_users, :created_at, :datetime, :null => true
    change_column :circles_users, :updated_at, :datetime, :null => true
  end
end
```

This isn't working. Any ideas on how to have those null values be set to true instead of false?

Comment: any error comes? or it's not working? -- did you run migration?

Comment: I ran rake db:migration, no text comes up, no errors, confirmations or anything

Comment: This ususally happens because it already ran, what are you trying to accomplish with this migration? Settin :null => true makes no sense to me. You are trying to define a defaul value, right?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
change_column :table_name, :created_at, :datetime, :null => true, :default => nil
```

and run migration

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to accomplish with this?

A datetime columns can't have its default value to true.

Read the spec: [Migrations](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html)

---

Rails does not support dynamic default values in migration script. SO if you want the current time you can easily add them at the model level.

1) Setting default values using `after_initialize` callback

```
class Test
  def after_initialize
    self.day ||= Date.today if new_record?
  end
end

t = Test.new
t.day # will return today's date
t.save
t.day # will return today's date
```

---

**Edit:**

In the comments we figured out that you don't want to worry filling the `updated_at` and `created_at` the thing is that ActiveRecord already do it for you.

So you don't have to remove nor change these columns.

"The timestamp columns created_at and updated_at which Active Record populates automatically will also be added." from [Migrations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html)

Hope it helps!

Comment: I'm trying to get my join table to save so I'll stop getting these errors when trying to create a new circles_users through creating a circle and updating its users attributes. Error: `SQLite3::ConstraintException: circles_users.created_at may not be NULL: INSERT INTO "circles_users" ("circle_id", "user_id") VALUES (11, 5)`

Comment: Yeah, I want to be able to save it without created_at and updated_at having to be present, since it's a join table, it doesn't automatically populate those to my knowledge

Comment: Oh, if that is your problem you are ok with it, it auto populates both columns, so you don't need to worry about it. Just edited the answer, please accept it!